# How to build Nuxt 3 as a Web Component to embed on another website

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, vite, custom-element

I am trying to embed a Nuxt 3 project on an external website as a Web Component (a chatbot SPA).

I have a working implementation of this in a Vue 3 project which uses Vue Custom Elements, example code [from the docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#definecustomelement):

```
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue'

const MyVueElement = defineCustomElement({
  // normal Vue component options here
  props: {},
  emits: {},
  template: `...`,

  // defineCustomElement only: CSS to be injected into shadow root
  styles: [`/* inlined css */`]
})

// Register the custom element.
// After registration, all `<my-vue-element>` tags
// on the page will be upgraded.
customElements.define('my-vue-element', MyVueElement)

// You can also programmatically instantiate the element:
// (can only be done after registration)
document.body.appendChild(
  new MyVueElement({
    // initial props (optional)
  })
)
```

```
// vite.config.js
// Bundle app into single js file

import cssInjectedByJsPlugin from "vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js";

...

    plugins: [cssInjectedByJsPlugin()]
    build: {
      cssCodeSplit: false,
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
          entryFileNames: "app.js",
        },
      },
    },
})
```

This project can then be embedded on any external web page by including the single JS output file and a `<my-vue-element></my-vue-element>`  element.

I haven't been able to successfully reuse this logic for Nuxt 3.

Any insight into how this may be achieved with Nuxt 3 would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How did this work out for you?